# Make substring bold within a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a substring bold without bolding the whole string.

Current code

```
client_info = 'Info as provided by the client'
print(client_info)
```

Current output

```
Info as provided by the client
```

Is there anyway that I can only bold the word 'client'?
Something like this?

Desired code

```
client_info = 'Info as provided by the <bold>client</bold>'
print(client_info)
```

Desired output

```
Info as provided by the **client**
```

Comment: Removed `pandas` tag as it's not required here.

Comment: @MayankPorwal That answer is totally different

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal Removed. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'\033[1m'` for turning a string to `bold`:

```
In [2753]: client_info = client_info.replace('client', '\033[1m' + 'client')

In [2754]: print(client_info)
Info as provided by the **client**
```

Comment: @MatthiasGallagher Please let me know if the answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into [html2markdown](https://pypi.org/project/html2markdown/) or [html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/) libraries that help you with such conversion.

If you only want to tackle the "bold" tags, then you could simply do something like:

```
client_info = client_info.replace('<bold>', '**')
client_info = client_info.replace('</bold>', '**')
```